# window.location.href navigates out of my website

Tags: javascript, html, css, video-streaming

Okay now i'm having a tough situation. I'm using a free html template. So far i have been able to do the following:

When a user clicks the thumbnail. The video will play where it should.

[image]

All i had to do with add the direct raw video file to the href of that image.

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="VIDEO_LINK.MP4"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/KWyIHw8.jpg" /></a>
```

Then i came accross a problem where the raw link would display on the bottom left of the browser.

I fixed it by adding an onclick event to form a function.

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="#" onclick="video();"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/KWyIHw8.jpg"/></a>
```

The function is:

```
Function video() {window.location.href = 'VIDEO_LINK_HERE.MP4'}
```

Well it turns out that now when i click the image it navigates the whole page to that link.

I need to know how i can make it play without navigating out of my website like in the first picture and most importantly not showing the raw video link.

Comment: did you try to remove the `href="#"`?? try like this `<a class="thumbnail" onclick="video();">`

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Just tried it, did not work man. Damn i have tried so many things to get it displaying on my site. I do not know why it navigates out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the jquery load func, to load the image in a specific div

```
$("#div1").load("http://i.imgur.com/KWyIHw8.jpg")
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are telling me. Why would i want to load the image on a separate div?